# In Biguqery, does a single slot consume multiple slots?

Tags: performance, google-bigquery

When I was reading a query plan about timeline information, I found that the information about "activeUnits" conflicted with that of "totalSlotMs".

I think that each "unit" in timeline information consumes a single slot. Therefore totalSlotMs is equal to the product of "activeUnits" and elapsed time. However, in my timeline information, totalSlotMs was more than twice as much as the product.

The timeline information is like the following

```
 {"activeUnits": "84", "completedUnits": "2673", "elapsedMs": "102776", "pendingUnits": "81", "totalSlotMs": "46827346"}, 

{"activeUnits": "84", "completedUnits": "2673", "elapsedMs": "103776", "pendingUnits": "81", "totalSlotMs": "47040505"},
```

The elapsed time between two sample is 1000ms, and totalSlotMs is increased 213159ms.
If an unit consumed a single slot, totalSlotMs was equal to 84000ms, which is much less than 213159ms.

Does a single slot consume multiple slots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **unit of work** is just a concept that means "a piece of work" and its not really useful for measuring something.
In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation#background) its said

> Within the query plan, the terms work units and workers are used to
>   convey information specifically about parallelism. Elsewhere within
>   BigQuery, you may encounter the term slot", which is an abstracted
>   representation of multiple facets of query execution, including
>   compute, memory, and I/O resources. Top level job statistics provide
>   the estimate of individual query cost using the totalSlotMs estimate
>   of the query using this abstracted accounting.

So I understand that a **work unity** can use many **slots** which explains your doubt.